# Surface display screen stops working after leaving cover on for a long time

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-surface, windows-rt

I recently upgraded my Surface with Windows RT to Windows RT 8.1. When I close the Type Cover, the screen shuts down as it should. However, if I leave the cover on overnight, the display screen refuses to turn on, though I can tell that the tablet is on because of the vibration upon tapping the Windows key. The only workaround I have discovered is to force shut down the tablet and turn it on, in which the display starts working again. This only started happening after I had upgraded it to 8.1, and I had also dropped it ~1-2 feet the same day. Is it because of the drop, or is it because of a bug in Windows RT 8.1 specifically with the Surface? If it is because of a bug, can someone point me to the filed bug, or tell me if I should file the bug myself? (I have a laptop with Windows 8.1 Preview, and it does not occur there if I leave the lid closed for extended periods of time).

**EDIT:** I have recently installed a system firmware update. I'll see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, you'd notice other issues if it were from the drop I would bet.  Though I haven't seen any other documented cases of this happening.

Comment: Have you tried and reset your device to factory settings to see if that helps?  Considering you will have to do this to install Windows RT 8.1 anyways its worth a try.

Comment: I'm going to try refreshing. @Ramhound No, you don't need to reset your tablet to install the final version of 8.1.

Comment: There is no upgrade path from the Preview to RTM all Windows Store applications will be reinstalled personal files are the only thing transferred this means Office will have to be reinstalled also. I am not wrong about this..

Comment: @Ramhound How do you know? I thought Office was a part of Windows RT, and I also got Outlook when I upgraded (or did I acquire it when I updated from the preview to the final version of Office RT that I did at the same time as the Windows 8.1 Preview update?). But I do know that all my Modern apps will need to be reinstalled. But anyway, I have Windows RT, so that means that I don't have any desktop apps (except IE and Office, of course).

Comment: It's well documented about Preview to RTM upgrade path. Yes Office will be reinstalled entirely new version after all.  The 8.0 to preview was an upgrade.  Read the documentation on Microaofts website

Comment: I got the same phenomenon a few days after I updated...thought it was fixed.